# Sum the columns of two dataframes of different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes：

**df1**

```
    country  value
0      aa      1
1      bb      1
2      cc      5
```

**df2**

```
     country  value
0      cc      8
1      aa      2
2      MM      1
3      FF      6
```

How get I can this dataframe (`df1` + `df2`) as follows:

```
    country  value
0      aa      3
1      bb      1
2      MM      1
3      cc      13
4      FF      6
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `set_index` and `add` with `fill_value=0`:

```
df1.set_index('country').add(df2.set_index('country'),fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  country  value
0      FF    6.0
1      MM    1.0
2      aa    3.0
3      bb    1.0
4      cc   13.0
```

Comment: which package is it? I can't reproduce it. Besides, what if I have many columns and I want to average out all of them? Thanks

Comment: pandas library... Would you create a new question?

Comment: And it goes without saying that one doesn’t need `set_index("country")` and `reset_index()` if the dataframes already share the same (partial) index (the purpose of `set_index("country")` in this answer actually being to set "country" as the shared index).

Answer (score 5):

You can first concatenate using `pd.concat`, then use `df.groupby`:

```
In [390]: pd.concat([df, df2]).groupby('country', as_index=False).sum()
Out[390]: 
  country  value
0      FF      6
1      MM      1
2      aa      3
3      bb      1
4      cc     13
```